# Calculating euclidean distances of forest areas to road infrastructure in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, proximity

I have prepared a forest cover map at 100 m resolution and have also created a euclidean distance layer of road infrastructure for that area at 100 m resolution. I would like to know how I can calculate the distance between each forest cell to the nearest road infrastructure. Should I overlay these two layers to find out which percentage of forest falls within a certain distance from the road?

Preferably in ArcGIS for Desktop.

Comment: Raster calculator distance*forest/forest. Reclassify output

Comment: Which of the three possible software products that you tagged are you actually wanting to ask about in this question?

Comment: Preferably in ArcGIS-Desktop

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Beneath your question you will find an [edit] button that can be used to revise your question with any requested clarifications at any time.

Comment: If you revert your question, it will be your answer, i.e.,  distance of forest cells to the road(s). For this create an euclidian distance raster with a value enough to cover all your forest patches and use Con operator to assign forest cells to the respective distance raster value. PS. Euclidian tool keeps the lowest value if there are overlapping, let's say, buffers.